# php pdo_dblib with sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I use PHP extension pdo_dblib to access MS SQL SERVER.
I used this connection:

```
$pdosql = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

I retrive the data from table:

```
$sql = 'SELECT cust_id FROM customers ORDER BY cust_id';
$rez = $pdosql->query($sql);
while($arr = $rez->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
    $sql1 = 'SELECT employee_name FROM employes ORDER BY emplyee_name';
    $rez1 = $pdosql->prepare($sql1);
    $rez1->bindValue(':id_cust',$arr[0],PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $rez1->execute();
    $arr1 = $rez1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    echo $arr1[0];
}
```

Instead to show first employee's name for all 20 customers, query return data only for first customer.
I found a solution to open a new PDO before `while`:

```
$pdosql = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```

And all works fine.
Is there another solution?

Because if I have `while` in `while`, the time to retrieve data is increasing.

If I used this code in mySQL database (with proper connection), all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the query inside the loop doesn't include the parameter.
Perhaps add "WHERE cust_id = :id_cust" to the query:

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT employee_name FROM employes WHERE cust_id = :id_cust ORDER BY emplyee_name';
```

Also, you may be able to optimize your code a bit by making one query the to database using a join. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    B.employee_name
FROM customers A 
INNER JOIN employees B 
ON      A.cust_id = B.cust_id
ORDER BY 
    A.cust_id
```

However, I'm also unsure of your database design and not sure how customers and employees are actually related.

Comment: No, it's my writing mistake. The correct syntax was: `$sql1 = 'SELECT employee_name FROM employes WHERE id_cust = :id_cust ORDER BY emplyee_name';`. Anyway, the problem is that second execute broke de loop, while is executed only once, even I has 20 customers and while must be executed for 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it is more practical to use an iner join in your query, using a field in common between the tables, that will show you the results you need, I recommend by experience or you want to use stored procedures.